# Image not loading in frame

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, paintcomponent

SO these aer the two different files that Im using:

```
    public class TestFunc {

    static BufferedImage img;   
    public static void main(String[] args){


        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);

        ShowImage I = new ShowImage();
        frame.getContentPane().add(I);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

and the other one:

```
public final class ShowImage extends JPanel{

Image image;

public ShowImage(){

    super();
    image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("Sunset.jpg");

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);

}

 }
```

However, there is nothing being displayed on the frame, and it appears blank. I'm pretty new to this, can't figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually there's nothing wrong with it as written -- it should work fine. Is "Sunset.jpg" a valid image, in the current directory when you run the program?

Comment: Yeah, I tried with different images as well, I'm not sure why its not displaying.

Comment: Requires full path name even if image is present in my directory. It works then. Is it because of the different packages present? (There's actually only one package in which all the working files are right now though)

Comment: The image won't be found on the classpath. The path is a literal path relative to the *current working directory*, the directory you're in when you type `java TestFunc`. As written above, the file would have to be right there in the working directory. Check out `ClassLoader.getResource()` and similar methods if you're interested in finding images on the class path.

Comment: @Andrew yeah the classes were all in the same package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an ImageIcon inside a JLabel:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        frame.add(jp);
        jp.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("d:\\temp\\me.JPG")));

        frame.pack();
```

Comment: `frame.setSize(600, 400); //bad` becomes redundant once `frame.pack(); //good` is called.  +1 for `ImageIcon` and `pack()`.

Comment: This works as well, if I give the full path name. Thanks! Whats the difference with the earlier method anyway? Yeah, removed the resize.

Comment: It would seem the image is not where you expected it to be, or at least was not being searched for where you expected it to be searched for.  Check the paths.

Comment: Well, the best completition would be to check out the SWING official tutorial. It has tons of useful stuff, and it's really well modularized such as you can only check out the parts you need and still get a good idea on how to use it. Here's the part for images: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html